# JQuery Image and Text Slider

Tags: jquery

I am working on a project in which I have to implement Image and Text Slider like  [this](http://www.pikachoose.com/) ,   and [this](http://galleria.io/), My structure of slide is like below(this is on one slide)

```
Question

Image

Answer
```

Where Images are optional,sometimes they appear sometimes not,but Questions and Answers are mandatory and on right side I will have Questions like in images are appearing in pikachoose below.

I have seen many sliders but each of those works only on images and not on text :(
Plus I want to implement Play, Pause and Shuffle with separate buttons.
Can anyone suggest some good slider which supports text, Thumbnail navigation and Separate control buttons.

Comment: https://github.com/CSS-Tricks/AnythingSlider  slide anything

Comment: It works only with images

Answer (score 0):

Just use a blank placeholder image if no image is provided? Then you can add anything you like to it...

Comment: A placeholder image means a default image for when there is no custom image set.

Comment: The placeholder image should be set/provided server-side... then it's no different form a "normal" image...